# Using Py2exe on whole package

Tags: python, windows, package, py2exe

I have a package that I am trying to package for Windows using py2exe. I can run the setup script and generate the executable just fine, but when I run it, I get an error that one of the modules in my package is not available for import. The error says: `ImportError: No module named 'some_functions'`This is the structure of the project:

```
project/
    setup.py
    icon.ico
    my_module/
        __init__.py
        some_functions.py
        __main__.py
```

This is my `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    version='1.1.1',
    console=[{
        'script': 'my_module/__main__.py',
        'icon_resources': [(1, 'icon.ico')],
        'dest_base': 'module'
    }],
    options={
        'py2exe': {
            'includes': [
                'requests'
            ],
            'bundle_files': 1
        }
    }
)
```

This is my `__main__.py`

```
from some_functions import important

print(important(10, 20))
```

And `some_functions.py`

```
def important(x, y):
    return x * y
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What's the point of making an executable out of a [Python package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=packages#packages), which is just a "collection of modules"?

Comment: I have to deploy this in an environment where not everyone can install the python runtime on their computer.

Comment: My point was that without an application, just having a bunch of modules "installed" -- not sure into what since there's no Python interpreter -- seems useless. py2exe would allow you create an executable that included the main application and any modules/packages it needed along with an Python interpreter to run code.

Comment: The module has a `__main__.py` That is the 'application'

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a long time since this question was asked but I was stuck with the same problem recently and I happen to find a solution that worked for me.

The module is not found because the `setup.py` file is in the parent directory. To work around this problem I just add the module directory to the path before calling `setup(...)` in the `setup.py` file:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'my_module')
```